# Formik checkbox causing so much delay on checking #1901

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6, formik, yup

React Formik-Yup Checkbox is causing so much delay whenever I check it or uncheck.
Here is the codesandbox for my issue-
https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-cdn-76xys?fontsize=14

I used two methods for my checkboxes group, but none work as expected.
One via binding handleCheckBox method to constructor, and then another by directly using handleChange of Formik.

Please help me resolve this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

// form constants
const restaurantTypeOptions = ["Delivery", "Take away", "Dine in"];
const restaurantSuitedOptions = ["Family", "Couple", "Cafe"];
const debug = true;

class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      restTypeArr: [],
      restSuitArr: []
    };
    this.handleCheckBox = this.handleCheckBox.bind(this);
  }

  handleCheckBox(e) {
    const newSelection = e.target.value;
    let newSelectionArray;

    if (Formik.values.restaurantType.indexOf(newSelection) > -1) {
      newSelectionArray = Formik.values.restaurantType.filter(
        s => s !== newSelection
      );
    } else {
      newSelectionArray = [...Formik.values.restaurantType, newSelection];
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      restTypeArr: newSelectionArray
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="signupContainer" className="signinup-container">
        <h3 className="mb-4"> Sign Up </h3>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            //restaurantType: ['Delivery', 'Take away'],
            restaurantType: this.state.restTypeArr,
            restaurantSuited: []
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            restaurantType: Yup.array().required("Please select at least one"),
            restaurantSuited: Yup.array().required("Please select at least one")
          })}
          onSubmit={(values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("Getting form values - ", values);
            }, 500);
          }}
          enableReinitialize={true}
        >
          {props => {
            const {
              values,
              touched,
              errors,
              isSubmitting,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              setFieldValue
            } = props;

            return (
              <Form id="signUpForm" className="signinupForm" noValidate>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-label" htmlFor="restaurantType">
                    Restaurant Type
                  </label>
                  <div className="checkbox-group">
                    {restaurantTypeOptions.map((option, index) => {
                      return (
                        <label
                          key={option}
                          index={index}
                          className="checkbox-inline"
                        >
                          <Field
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="restaurantType"
                            value={option}
                            id={option}
                            checked={values.restaurantType.indexOf(option) > -1}
                            onChange={this.handleCheckBox}
                          />
                          {option}
                        </label>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name="restaurantType"
                    component="span"
                    className="invalid-input"
                  />
                </div>
                {/* Restaurant Type */}

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-label" htmlFor="restaurantSuited">
                    Restaurant Suited for
                  </label>
                  <div className="checkbox-group">
                    {restaurantSuitedOptions.map(option => {
                      return (
                        <label key={option} className="checkbox-inline">
                          <Field
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="restaurantSuited"
                            value={option}
                            checked={
                              values.restaurantSuited.indexOf(option) > -1
                            }
                            //onChange={() => setFieldValue("restaurantSuited", option)}
                            onChange={() => {
                              if (values.restaurantSuited.includes(option)) {
                                values.restaurantSuited.pop(option);
                              } else {
                                values.restaurantSuited.push(option);
                              }
                            }}
                          />
                          {option}
                        </label>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name="restaurantSuited"
                    component="span"
                    className="invalid-input"
                  />
                </div>
                {/* Restaurant Suited */}

                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-filled"
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                >
                  SignUp
                </button>
                {/*Submit */}

                {debug && (
                  <>
                    <pre style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                      <strong>Values</strong>
                      <br />
                      {JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}
                    </pre>
                    <pre style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                      <strong>Errors</strong>
                      <br />
                      {JSON.stringify(errors, null, 2)}
                    </pre>
                  </>
                )}
              </Form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUp;
```

Comment: Remove this line  `checked={values.restaurantType.indexOf(option) > -1}`, it is never changed

Comment: Thanks @Michael. But can you explain the reasons?

Comment: Sure but because of the word limit in comment I'll use answer

Comment: @Gaurav can you clarify what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might explain it wrong, if someone could correct me please do so.

By using `checked` then the check box would be set to that value, but without being able to change `values.restaurantType.indexOf(option) > -1` the value will be stuck forever, if your intention is to set default check please use `defaultChecked`.

Otherwise you'll have to use state with `onChange`.
I can see that you had used onChange with state, but the value of `values.restaurantType.indexOf(option) > -1` is mapped with props, but since props is immutable then the value will never be changed

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael. I'll appreciate if you can also look into this issue that I am running for last 3 days. - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58484239/7682925

Comment: hi michael, please help me in this react formik problem - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59408716/7682925