# Redirect doesn;t work, while {this.props.history} does

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

While an action is successful, redirect is not working but history.replace is working.
Why??

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="loginContainer" className="signinup-container">
        <h3 className="mb-4"> Log In </h3>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            email: "",
            password: "",
            rememberMe: false,
            error: ""
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            email: Yup.string()
              .required("Please enter email to login.")
              .email("Please enter a valid email."),
            password: Yup.string().required("Please enter your password.")
          })}
          onSubmit={(values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("Logging in", values);
              setSubmitting(false);
              return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
              //this.props.history.replace("/dashboard");
              //this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
            }, 500);
          }}
        >
          {props => {
            const {
              values,
              touched,
              errors,
              isSubmitting,
              handleChange
            } = props;

            return (
              <Form id="loginForm" className="signinupForm" noValidate>
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="error"
                  component="span"
                  className="login-error"
                />
                <div className="form-group ">
                  <label className="form-label" htmlFor="email">
                    Email
                  </label>
                  <Field
                    type={"email"}
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    className={
                      "form-control" +
                      (errors.email && touched.email ? " is-invalid" : "")
                    }
                  />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name="email"
                    component="span"
                    className="invalid-input"
                  />
                </div>
                {/* Email */}
                <div className="form-group position-relative">
                  <label className="form-label" htmlFor="password">
                    Password
                  </label>
                  <Field
                    type={"password"}
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                    className={
                      "form-control" +
                      (errors.password && touched.password ? " is-invalid" : "")
                    }
                  />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name="password"
                    component="span"
                    className="invalid-input"
                  />
                </div>
                {/* Password */}
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-label" htmlFor="rememberMe">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="rememberMe"
                      name="rememberMe"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      defaultChecked={values.rememberMe}
                      value={values.rememberMe}
                    />
                    Remember me
                  </label>
                </div>
                {/* Rememeber Me */}
                {isSubmitting ? (
                  <span className="loader-gif">loading</span>
                ) : null}
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-filled"
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                >
                  Login
                </button>
                {/*Submit */}
              </Form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Please go to login page and check this.
Codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-hooks-s9vgx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling your Redirect JSX component from onSubmit method. However you cannot do that since you need to return the JSX elements from within the render method which is why you need to use `history to update route`

```
     onSubmit={(values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("Logging in", values);
          setSubmitting(false);
          this.props.history.replace("/dashboard");
        }, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks @shubham-khatri 
Can you please look into this bug ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502707/react-select-with-formik-not-updating-select-field-but-does-everything-else

Comment: Hi @Shubham-Khatri, can you please help me in this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809648/how-to-validate-multiple-phone-numbers-with-formik-yup  I'm stuck for last 3 days

Answer (score 1):

You must be using slash:

```
to='/dashboard'
```

Answer (score 1):

As what [@Shubham Khatri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58484419/10910506) said, but if you want to use `<Redirect>` you can create a state and detect if logged and then redirect it, like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-https-8zeeu).

Changes are adding

```
 this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false
    };
```

And in render

```
if (this.state.isLoggedIn) return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
```

in onSubmit

```
this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
```

Comment: Hi @Michael
Can you please look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809648/how-to-validate-multiple-phone-numbers-with-formik-yup

Comment: Hi Michael, please help me in this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59408716/7682925