# How to Validate Multiple Phone Numbers with Formik Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, formik, yup

I am building a form a where a user can store multiple phone numbers and set the privacy of that number (whether he wants the number to be publicly displayed or not).

I have succesfully created the form but stuck in **formik-yup validation** and **getting the values** (phone number with privacy value) to further send it to backend.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage, FieldArray } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

import DropDown from "./DropDown";

const phoneNumberPrivacyDropdown = [
  { value: "private", option: "Private" },
  { value: "public", option: "Public" }
];
const phoneRegExp = /^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/; // for Mobile Numbers

export default class PhoneNumbers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      phoneNumbers: [{ privacy: "", number: "" }]
    };
    this.addNewPhoneNumber = this.addNewPhoneNumber.bind(this);
    this.removePhoneNumber = this.removePhoneNumber.bind(this);
  }
  addNewPhoneNumber() {
    let newPhoneNumber = { privacy: "", number: "" };
    this.setState({
      phoneNumbers: [...this.state.phoneNumbers, newPhoneNumber]
    });
  }
  removePhoneNumber = key => {
    let phoneNumbers = this.state.phoneNumbers;
    phoneNumbers.splice(key, 1);
    this.setState({
      phoneNumbers: phoneNumbers
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="form-subHead">Multiple Phone Numbers.</h1>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            phoneNumbers: this.state.phoneNumbers
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            phoneNumbers: Yup.array().of(
              Yup.object().shape({
                mobile: Yup.string()
                  .required("Please tell us your mobile number.")
                  .length(10, "Please enter a valid mobile number.")
                  .matches(phoneRegExp, "Please enter a valid mobile number.")
              })
            )
          })}
          onSubmit={(values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("Getting form values - ", values);
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 500);
          }}
          enableReinitialize={true}
        >
          {props => {
            const {
              values,
              touched,
              dirty,
              errors,
              isSubmitting,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              setFieldValue,
              setFieldTouched
            } = props;

            return (
              <Form id="signUpForm" className="signinupForm mt-4" noValidate>
                <div className="formSection">
                  <div className="row form-row">
                    <div className="col-sm-6">
                      <div className="form-group phoneNumberGroup">
                        <label htmlFor="phoneNumbers" className="form-label">
                          Phone Number
                        </label>
                        {this.state.phoneNumbers.map((phoneNumber, i) => (
                          <div className="phoneNumber" key={i}>
                            <Field
                              type="number"
                              name={`phone${i + 1}`}
                              placeholder="Contact Number"
                              className="form-control mobileNumber"
                            />
                            <div className="selectPhonePrivacy">
                              <DropDown
                                items={phoneNumberPrivacyDropdown}
                                inputname="phonePrivacy"
                                showIconOnly={false}
                              />
                            </div>
                            {i != 0 && (
                              <span
                                className="modifyInput removeElement"
                                onClick={() => this.removePhoneNumber({ i })}
                              >
                                -
                              </span>
                            )}
                            <ErrorMessage
                              name="mobile"
                              component="span"
                              className="invalid-input"
                            />
                          </div>
                        ))}
                        {this.state.phoneNumbers.length <= 2 && ( // only upto 3 phone numbers allowed!
                          <a
                            className="modifyInput addElement"
                            onClick={this.addNewPhoneNumber}
                          >
                            Add Another Phone
                          </a>
                        )}
                      </div>
                      {/* Phone Numbers Group */}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="text-center">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    className="btn btn-filled"
                    disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
                  >
                    Finish
                  </button>
                  {/*Submit */}
                </div>
              </Form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a codesandbox demo for the actual codes - 
https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-field-validation-7t1ww